# How to add icons\thumbnails to wpf listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, thumbnails

I want to have two list-boxes which contain icons\thumbnails and then drag and drop items between the two.

Each list represent a folder and the drug and drop represents moving the file.

1. I need some help on how to create the list of icons... it seems different from the winforms.
2. I need help with drag and drop of the icons. (just nice to have...)

Thanks

Comment: Snowbear...your comment, funny as it may be is not that helpful. But if someone will find it funny...emmmm... I like happy people :)

Comment: It was my way to point out the typo ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/filetoiconconverter.aspx).